# Use of undeclared identified isDir

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to use the following code:

```
if(![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:mountPath isDirectory:&isDir])
```

But I get 'Use of undeclared identified isDir'

I've used `#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>` in my header file.

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are supposed to pass BOOL variable over there for `isDir`, you can use as below:

```
BOOL isDir; /* NO/YES */
if(![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:mountPath isDirectory:&isDir])
```

Comment: Could have sworn I had tried this and got the warning "incompatible pointer conversion sending 'BOOL' to BOOL *

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that you have not declared what `isDir` variable.

At least not at a point where your if-statement can see it. Take a look at this example use of the method

```
BOOL isDirectory;
if ([self fileExistsAtPath:@"/Some/Path/aFolder" isDirectory:&isDirectory] && isDirectory)
{
    // aFolder exists and is a directory...
}
```

Comment: Could have sworn I had tried this and got the warning "incompatible pointer conversion sending 'BOOL' to BOOL *

Answer (score 0):

What is `isDir` meant to be pointing to?

That error message means that you haven't defined the variable.

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if `isDir` is not declared (see other answers). If you don't need to know whether it actually is a directory or not, you can simply use

```
if(![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:mountPath isDirectory:NULL]) {
    // ...
}

// or even more simple

if(![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:mountPath]) {
    // ...
}
```

For further reference, see [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html).